# Get Background Color of a View in hex

Tags: android, user-interface, view, colors, background

I want to get background color of a view in hex format.

for example consider `int getViewBackgroundColor(View view)` my excepted return vaule is `0Xff256e78`.

How could I do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay1);
ColorDrawable viewColor = (ColorDrawable) layout.getBackground();
int colorId = viewColor.getColor();
```

After getting as integer type of color, now you have to convert to hexadecimal:

```
String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & colorId));
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: thanks it works but it's String , to get it in long -> `Long.parseLong(hexColorString, 16)`

Answer (score 0):

The following code will get the background color of a view and convert it to the int representation of the color.

```
ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) myView.getBackground();
int colorId = buttonColor.getColor();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer in Kotlin language:

```
var view: View = findViewById(R.id.bg_view_id)
var draw: ColorDrawable = view.background as ColorDrawable
var color_id = draw.getColor()

Log.i("UYARI-INFO: ", Integer.toHexString(color_id))
```

Output in Logcat will be:

```
I/UYARI-INFO:: ffffd8af
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not different from the other answers, but it's the shortest:

```
((ColorDrawable)yourView.getBackground()).getColor()
```